# EventAggregator - Get List of Subscribers

Tags: unity-container, prism, eventaggregator

Using EventAggregator with Unity and PRISM, is there a way to get the list of subscribers to a specific event?

I know that some people will say that "Why do you want to know this, the whole point of using an EventAggregator is so that we don't care who or how many subscribers".

This is purely an exercise that I want to carry out it is not for any specific purpose.

EventAggregator must store a list of subscribers is there a way to expose this list?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the subscriber information is contained within the `EventAggregator` object graph.  Unfortunately (for your request), this information is stored within private fields.

Events are stored in a private `Dictionary<Type, EventBase> events`.  The subscriptions are stored within the event itself (in `EventBase`) as a

```cs
private readonly List<IEventSubscription> _subscriptions = new List<IEventSubscription>();
```

One option to retrieve the subscription information is to use reflection to access the private member variables (assuming reflection permission exists).

If you can modify the events then another option is to expose this information via the specific `PubSub<EventBase>` since `EventBase` allows access to subscriptions for subclasses via the `protected ICollection<IEventSubscription> Subscriptions` property.  For example:

```cs
public class MyEvent : PubSubEvent<MyEventData>
{
    public new ICollection<IEventSubscription> Subscriptions => base.Subscriptions;
}
```

Then you can query the event:

```cs
var myEvent = eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>();
var sub = (EventSubscription<MyEventData>) myEvent.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault();
MethodInfo method = sub.Action.Method;
object target = sub.Action.Target;
```

If you don't need the specific `EventSubscription<T>` data (e.g. just want to know subscription counts) then you could avoid the specific cast and use the `IEventSubscription` interface.

Comment: I see value in the question.  Sometimes when code needs to be revisited and reworked, eventAggregator seemingly work against because it is hard to debug and follow the sequence of handlings by all the subscribers which need to be visible and considered as part of revisit.   Do you see some downside, cons in using EventAggregator?  It becomes like a spider web hard to trace sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this really helps.! :)